# Python: Get javascript file from href tag of html

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, web-scraping

Consider a website similar to this one:

http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/COsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=3055311

As one can see, the website contains links to pdf files referenced by an href tag in the page source, e.g.:

```
<a href="javascript:$('form_cofo_pdf_view_B000114563.PDF').submit();">B000114563.PDF</a>
```

I would like to open the underlying file using python, effectively scraping the results.

```
req = urllib2.Request("link.com")
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get("href"))
```

Normally I would just connect the base url with the href url to get the documents, but here, they are referenced with javascript. Hence I am not entirely sure how to access the files.

I would prefer to use urrlib2 and BeautifulSoup and not switch to Selenium to click on links. Does anyone have an idea to accomplish that? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `href` is only string so you can use string functions to get substring with filename. Download file normally in browser and check its full url - maybe you find base url for this file and you can use it next time.

Comment: The "link" is done by submitting a form. You'll have to find out what that form contains and where it's sending that data to. Then you have to replicate that request. Not really something you can automate too easily. It's going to be very specific to that page.

Comment: It could be restricted, meaning that the access to it could be going through a PHP or anything really...

Comment: So you're saying I should click on the link in the browser and check how the url changes? Because I did that and it does not include anything related to the `B000114563.PDF` in the `href` link.

Comment: @DamianChrzanowski: PHP would mean I need to use Selenium?

Comment: This file is downloaded from http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/CofoDocumentContentServlet?cofomatadata1=cofo&cofomatadata2=B&cofomatadata3=000&cofomatadata4=114000&cofomatadata5=B000114563.PDF  and all elements required in this url you have in name `form_cofo_pdf_view_B000114563.PDF`

Comment: what @furas said. The api is exposed

Comment: Oh I see, but the parameter `cofomatadata4=` is different too, not just `cofomatadata5=`. And I don't really know where the value for the former comes from, as the latter is just equal to [id].PDF. For example, the first document has `cofomatadata4=11400` while the last one has `cofomatadata4=11600`.

Comment: you have 114 in first name and 116 in last name. code: http://pastebin.com/kt72GSyYa (but tested only with one page)

Comment: @furas: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded few files and compared direct link with its name and all elements required in link you have in filename

Filename:

```
form_cofo_pdf_view_B000114563.PDF
```

Direct link:

```
http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/CofoDocumentContentServlet
?passjobnumber=null
&cofomatadata1=cofo
&cofomatadata2=B
&cofomatadata3=000
&cofomatadata4=114000
&cofomatadata5=B000114563.PDF
```

So you can create direct link when you get filename from string `javascript:$('form_cofo_pdf_view_B000114563.PDF').submit();`

Working code: http://pastebin.com/kt72GSyYa